# Linux VM can not connect to the internet

Tags: linux, internet, nat

I'm trying to set up an virtual server with connection to the internet.

When I start a ping to the local network, there are no problems. When I try to ping an address from the internet, it shows that the ping has been filtered. the host machine has a normal internet connection, which works fine. I can ping and access everything.

Is there maybe a problem with NAT?

Comment: Please provide more details of the setup. At this point it could be anything from an issue with the service provider upstream, to misconfiguration locally, or that you're using Qemu and a userspace network stack where ICMP hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Could you tell us what sort of virtualization solution you're using - Virtualbox? VMWare? KVM? Xen? It might also help to know about your network setup. Additionally, what do you mean a ping to the local network? Sometimes there's a difference between pinging the IP of your router or the IP of the host and an actual client on your LAN.